# vba: find last row fails with error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code from http://ccm.net/faq/14494-vba-last-non-empty-row-all-versions

```
Function lastRow(sheet As Worksheet) As Long

lastRow = sheet.Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row

End Function
```

It works if the sheet contains something. If it is empty or has had content it fails with error 91 (object variable or with block variable not set).

Why ?

Comment: It fails because there is nothing to find....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
Function lastRow(sheet As Worksheet) As Variant
   Dim r As Range, lr As Long
   Set r = sheet.Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
   If r Is Nothing Then
      lastRow = "Nothing in column"
   Else
      lastRow = r.Row
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: It is better to use `xlByRows` instead of `xlByColumns` because in case `xlByColumns` searching goes by columns, for example if you will have values in `[A10]` and `[B9]` then `find` with using `xlByColumns` will return you 9 row instead of 10. So `xlByColumns` is better to use when you trying to find the last column, not the row. Of course, your code will return correct number due to used `Columns(1)` range, but in case when used `Cells.` you may have a problem with that.